# how to get a Handler of a specific eclipse.core.command

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm building an Eclipse plug-in that makes use of `org.eclipse.core.commands`

I have implemented `IHandler` and have declared the commands with the associated handler class in the `plugin.xml`, and now I am looking for a way to get the instance of the `IHandler` in another part of the application, in order to set a state of the command

From the `IHandlerService` I can only execute a command or activate a command when knowing the handler.

Should I abandon specifying the `Handler` in `plugin.xml` and only activate programmatically, having the command defined in plugin.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask the `ICommandService` to return a `Command` for the command that you declared. `Command#getHandler` will then return your handler.

Note that if there are multiple handlers for a given command,  the *active* handler will be returned or `null` if there is no active handler.

Comment: happiness++ Dankeschön